# How create Excel Table in C#

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I'm developing a Excel add-in in C#, and now I want to create a Excel Simple Table just like this:

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC299689.bmp

My data will come from a `List<T>` , and I want to do something like :
1. create table
2. create headers
3. foreach(item in List) (column 1 = tfield 1)

Very simple, but I can't find a solution anywhere..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to create an Excel table with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766205/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-an-excel-table-with-c)

Comment: It's not the same, this example, just "insert" the data in excel Worksheet. I wanna create a Table as if created in Excel. Lika this -> http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC299689.bmp

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/137183/Tip-Format-an-Excel-Range-as-a-Table-Programatical

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which offers a lot of functionality for working with EXCEL. cheers!